# Setting the cookies to webbrowser control in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want set the cookie to Webbrowser control before or while navigating to that page. I am able to set the cookie in the Navigated event but i am not able set the cookie in the Navigating event of Webbrowser control.

I am trying below code to set the cookie:

```
 webbrowser.InvokeScript("document.cookie=" + cookie_name+ "=" + cookie_value);
```

If i try the above code i am getting error saying that **"An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020006."**

I even tried below URL to set the cookie on the werbbrowser control but still i am not able to set the cookie on the browser:
http://christian-helle.blogspot.in/2012/03/integrating-html5-and-javascript-with.html

**Edit:**

Here i am trying to set the cookie for the Webbrowser control not for the HttpWebRequest. We can set the cookie for the HttpWebRequest and we can fetch the html but HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer won't set cookie to the Webbrowser.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

You can get the cookies with this:

```
CookieCollection tempCookies = Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserExtensions.GetCookies(this.BrowserControl);
```

And set them with this:

```
string CookieHeaders = "Cookies: SomeCookie=value1; SomeCookie2=value2; SomeCookie2=value2"
this.BrowserControl.Navigate(new Uri(URL), new byte[0], CookieHeaders);
```

Comment: Don't be that specific... For what version of WP doesn't it work?

Comment: Sorry! I'm working on a WP 8.1 SL application. Did you ever see your solution working? I've read (and tested) around on google that setting the cookie header on the WebBrowser control is not supported!

Comment: Yes, this actually work for me on real devices! But i don't know anymore for which version. I think it was for Windows Phone 8, but perhaps 7. But surely not WP 8.1 since it wasn't released then.

Cookies aren't supported, as of CookieCollection and so on aren't supported. But since cookies are just additional HTTP headers, you can totally use them in the Navigate function of the WebControl class. For more information please take a look at the official documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If i'm not wrong the standard header for cookies is the Set-Cookie. Using that WP throw an exception. Using Cookie as header shows no exceptions but does not work!

Comment: Set-Cookie might be some function to also set the cookies, i don't known. But as of WebControl.Navigate your're just creating a HTTP request and add some cookies using the last parameter of the function.